# Multiply matrix or vector by a scalar in c

Tags: c, matrix, multiplication

Is there a function in C language to calculate directely without using a loop the multiplication of a matrix by a scalar value ?

Comment: No. You need to write by your self.

Comment: So easy to make... Do you need help maybe?

Comment: like matlab doesn't exist ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Generally, C only implements type operations. An array is a sequential arrangement of data of a type. Thus it does not have intrinsic operations that collection types may have in other languages, only those that may be performed on each data of whatever type the data is of.

i.e. `int myArray[5];` is an array of integers so I could perform integer operations valid for integers on each data in the array, but there is no collective array type, so it is not possible to perform operations on the array as a whole.

Comment: C does have functions that operate on arrays, e.g. `qsort` and `bsearch`.

Comment: They are functions, not operators. I would imagine they use loops or at least pointer arithmetic. And AFAIK there is none that do what is asked.

Comment: Well for scalar by matrix multiplication you need to multiply every matrix value by the scalar value. A matrix could be represented in C by a two dimensional array, with columns in on dimension and rows in the other. Matrices are stored contiguously, so `int martrixArray[n][m]` is equivalent to a pointer that can be dereferenced by `*matrixArray`, which would point at the first element. Thus multiplying `*matrixArray` by the scalar resolves the first matrix element. Then add one to the poiner (`matrixArray`) and repeat until you have multiplied m*n times as that would be the end of the array.

Comment: e.g. for an array (the matrix) `A[2][2]` and an int (the scalar) `B` the following could be used: 
`*A++ * B; *A++ * B; A++ * B; A++ * B;`